# Mocha async requests to Node.js API

Tags: mocha.js, node-async, node-request

I am using mocha to test a Node.js API I am writing. I need mocha to send, for example, 100 HTTP requests all at once and then have 100 callbacks waiting for response data. And then after all 100 of those calls are done, I need to run another series of 100 HTTP requests.

What I know about Mocha: each **side by side** describe function call runs synchronously. Within one describe, I run the 100 HTTP requests using `async` (which is what most Stackoverflow responses told me to do.

Right now I am having trouble with just getting these HTTP requests to run in asynchronous. Each `it` is supposed to be asynchronous but it is definitely not the case when waiting for request data

```
var registeredData = {};
describe("Run first 100 HTTP requests...", function () {
    async.map(calls, function (call, callback) {
        it('call '+call.num, function(done) {
            request({
                method: 'POST',
                uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/register',
                json: {
                    data: { 
                        name: call.name,
                        id: call.id
                    }
                },
            }, 
            function (err, res) {
                expect(res.body).to.exist;
                registeredData[call.num] = res.body.info;
                done();
            });
        });
        callback();
    });
});    
describe("Run next 100 HTTP requests...", function () {
    async.map(calls, function (call, callback) {
        it('call '+call.num, function(done) {
            request({
                method: 'POST',
                uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/getData',
                json: {
                    data: {
                        dataFor: registeredData[call.num] 
                    }
                },
            }, 
            function (err, res) {
                expect(res.body).to.exist;
                done();
            });
        });
        callback();
    });
});
```

Basically, the first 100 HTTP requests register accounts, and the next 100 retrieve info for each respective account. I don't know when to call `done()` and when to call `callback()` (pertaining to `async.map`). Anybody know what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I do not see the point here to use `async.map` in your code.

## Given 100 requests send all of them in a single test

In case your test case is "Send 100 requests and test that they all return" you have to use `async` in your test.

```
it("Run first 100 HTTP requests...", function (done) {

  function sendRequest(call, next){
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/register',
        json: {
          data: { 
            name: call.name,
            id: call.id
          }
        },
      },
      function (err, res) {
        if(err){
          next(err);
        } else {
          expect(res.body).to.exist;
          // ... more assertions here
          next();
        }
      });
  }

  async.series(calls, sendRequest, done);

});
... more tests here
```

## Given a list of 100 calls test each single call

If what you want to do is to have a list of calls and have a `it` test for each of them then you can just produce a new `it` clojure for each call.
`mocha` will register the `it` tests and then execute them.

```
var registeredData = {};
describe("Run first 100 HTTP requests...", function () {

  function createCallTest(call){
    it('call '+call.num, function(done) {

      request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/register',
        json: {
          data: { 
            name: call.name,
            id: call.id
          }
        },
      },
      function (err, res) {
        expect(res.body).to.exist;
        registeredData[call.num] = res.body.info;
        done();
      });
    });
  }

  // generate one test for each calls entry
  calls.forEach(function(call){

    createCallTest(call);

  });
});
... more tests here
```

Comment: yeah you're right, I took out the async.map. But these requests are sent in one after another. I have two terminals up, one for the API and the other for mocha tests sending requests, and the API is not receiving all the calls asynchronously. request is blocking every subsequent call until the previous is returned

Comment: If you want concurrent calls I'd recommend to group them: even if you fire them all together usually there's a maximum number of calls that can be open in parallel. I believe that 100 is far above that cap.

Comment: well I can't even get 2 concurrent calls with this though

Comment: Ok, then I think the answer above is not right as it is. I will update it.

Comment: Is there a way to tweak this so that each request is an `it` in mocha (so 100 `it` tests)? Because each call would be an individual test (I am using 100 as an arbitrary number here, it could be 5, 10, 20, etc.). I need each `it` to be individual print statement saying that the request was successful. But I don't know how to order the callbacks

Comment: You want to run 100 requests in parallel but each request to be a standalone test?

Comment: Yes. I used 100 for the principle. I would need to run maybe 10 or more tests that scrape websites. Since these are extremely slow, I need them to run in parallel all as separate tests so that I may see what is wrong with each individual call when multiple calls fail. If I have them all in one `it`, it would not help me much to address each minor scraping issue

Comment: Mmmm. `it` function s can only be executed sequencially in `mocha` or `jasmine` or any other test runner. There are two solution I can think on top of my head: run all your requests in a `before` block, collect the results and then test sequencially the returned results. The second solution will require you to change test runner and use `ava` instead of `mocha`, which performs concurrent testing: I'd keep this as a last resort though and give a go to the first one.